# how to use lambda in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, lambda, anglesharp

When I use AngleSharp in VB.NET, the lambda in C# becomes a question. VB.NET can use `function` to replace lambda but seem to accept only one argument

```
Dim document = Await context.OpenAsync(Function(Res)
Res.Content("

")
.Address("http://localhost/")
.Header(HeaderNames.SetCookie, my_headers)
End Function
)
```

The errors:

```
Error BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OpenAsync' can be called with these arguments:
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(response As IResponse, [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'IResponse' because 'IResponse' is not a delegate type.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As DocumentRequest, [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'DocumentRequest' because 'DocumentRequest' is not a delegate type.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(url As Url, [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'Url' because 'Url' is not a delegate type.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': 'HeaderNames' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': 'HeaderNames' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(address As String, [cancellation As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'String' because 'String' is not a delegate type.
```

How do I fix it?

the errors after modifying by 41686d6564

```
Error   BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OpenAsync' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(response As IResponse, [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'IResponse' because 'IResponse' is not a delegate type.
    Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As DocumentRequest, [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'DocumentRequest' because 'DocumentRequest' is not a delegate type.
    Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(url As Url, [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'Url' because 'Url' is not a delegate type.
    Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': 'Return' statement in a Sub or a Set cannot return a value.
    Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(request As Action(Of VirtualResponse), [cancel As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': 'HeaderNames' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
    Extension method 'Public Function OpenAsync(address As String, [cancellation As CancellationToken = Nothing]) As Task(Of IDocument)' defined in 'BrowsingContextExtensions': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'String' because 'String' is not a delegate type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The [overload](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/AngleSharp.IBrowsingContext.OpenAsync(System.Action,%20System.Threading.CancellationToken)/) that you're trying to use takes an `Action`, not a `Func`. Therefore, you ought to use `Sub` instead of `Function`.
2. In VB, the dot has to come at the end of the line, not at the beginning of the next one (in C#, you may do either), or else the [line continuation character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30999) (i.e., `_`) must be used.

Changing your code to something like the following should make it compile:

```
Dim document = Await context.OpenAsync(
    Sub(Res)
        Res.Content("").
        Address("http://localhost/").
        Header(HeaderNames.SetCookie, my_headers)
    End Sub)
```

Or using explicit line continuation:

```
Dim document = Await context.OpenAsync(
    Sub(Res)
        Res.Content("") _
        .Address("http://localhost/") _
        .Header(HeaderNames.SetCookie, my_headers)
    End Sub)
```

Comment: thx,but the program still have some problems

Comment: @邱子恩 Please read the error messages that you're getting. They tell you exactly what's wrong (which we can't infer based on the sample code you provided). It looks like you're using a `Return` statement inside the Sub (you shouldn't) and that `HeaderNames` is inaccessible (you probably want to import the `Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers` namespace).

Comment: @416866564 thx,my program can run.

Comment: `.` at the beginning of the line can be done in VB, but it requires an explicit line continuation i.e. space followed by `_` on the previous line.

Comment: @Craig Yes, that's right. Been a long while since I needed to use the line continuation character. I've approved your suggested edit but included both options in the answer.